# convert oracle date string to number

Tags: oracle

I need to convert a date string -'2013-01-01' to number --20130101 type..How can I accomplish it in Oracle efficiently?

```
    My Input-

'2013-01-01'

   My Output

    Output-20130101
```

Comment: Do you have a current method that you've disregarded as non-efficient?

Comment: TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2013-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYYMMDD'),99999999)

Comment: nothing wrong with that, I'd have accepted that as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
select to_number(replace('2013-01-01', '-')) from dual;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the string to date and convert back using the format that you want to:

```
select to_char(to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD');
```

More information about datetime format:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
   to_char(your_date,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Just the basics of using to_char with a date here.

Comment: the input is a string, not a date.

Answer (score 1):

You can also "exploit" the format mask:

```
select to_number('2013-01-01', '9999G99G99', 'nls_numeric_characters=,-')
from dual
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/7225)

Answer (score 1):

To convert date string to number:

Always convert it to char first then to number:

```
Select TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(to_date('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYYMMDD')) from dual
```

if your column datatype is DATE then use your column name in place of sysdate in the below:

```
Select TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')) from dual
```